# ConvertSidToStringSid on SID obtained from a different machine

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm curious if [ConvertSidToStringSid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will be able to convert a binary SID that was obtained from a totally different machine than the one this API is called on?

The SID is obtained on the source machine by calling:

```
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, , , );
```

and then the size of the binary array for SID itself is calculated using `GetLengthSid()` API.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, since it's just converting the bits in the SID to string form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does sometimes needs to manipulate foreign SIDs, e.g., if you connect to a file share on another machine, or connect an external NTFS-formatted disk that has been used on another machine.  So it is perfectly capable of doing so.

You'll run into trouble if you try to convert the SID to a username, of course.  But something as simple as turning a binary SID into string representation, or vice-versa, will work perfectly.